# Track multiple touch down's / up's with libevdev

Tags: c, linux, evdev

I'm using libevdev and having trouble understanding how I can detect multiple touch downs / ups.  As shown on this libevdev [tutorial](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2016/09/understanding-evdev.html) you can see that on the last example on the page, there are two touches occuring.  However, only two`BTN_TOUCH`events are received, one for the first finger down, and then when the last finger comes up.  No `BTN_TOUCH` happens for the second / intermediate touches.  So how can I know when a second touch goes up and comes back down (ie, transition from a two finger gesture to a one finger gesture)?

Here's my log for two finger's down and both back up:

```
EV_KEY  BTN_TOOL_FINGER ), value 1
EV_KEY  BTN_TOUCH ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID ), value 0
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_X ), value 1718
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_Y ), value 1161
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_PRESSURE ), value 51
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_ORIENTATION ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_MT_REPORT ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_REPORT ), value 0
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID ), value 0
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_X ), value 1718
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_Y ), value 1161
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_PRESSURE ), value 51
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_ORIENTATION ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_MT_REPORT ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_REPORT ), value 0
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID ), value 0
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_X ), value 1717
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_Y ), value 1159
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_PRESSURE ), value 43
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_ORIENTATION ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_MT_REPORT ), value 0
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_X ), value 2148
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_POSITION_Y ), value 1066
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_PRESSURE ), value 18
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR ), value 1
EV_ABS  ABS_MT_ORIENTATION ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_MT_REPORT ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_REPORT ), value 0
EV_KEY  BTN_TOUCH ), value 0
EV_KEY  BTN_TOOL_FINGER ), value 0
EV_SYN  SYN_REPORT ), value 0
```

And when one finger comes up and goes back down, while another finger remains on the screen, all I get is repeating portions of this:

```
(EV_ABS), code 57( 57 -> 32, 32 == ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID ), value 0
(EV_ABS), code 53( 53 -> 47, 47 == ABS_MT_POSITION_X ), value 1395
(EV_ABS), code 54( 54 -> 0, 65506 == ABS_MT_POSITION_Y ), value 2086
(EV_ABS), code 58( 58 -> 0, 65509 == ABS_MT_PRESSURE ), value 127
(EV_ABS), code 48( 48 -> 98, 98 == ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR ), value 1
(EV_ABS), code 49( 49 -> 110, 110 == ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR ), value 1
(EV_ABS), code 52( 52 -> 46, 46 == ABS_MT_ORIENTATION ), value 0
(EV_SYN), code 2( 2 -> 49, 49 == SYN_MT_REPORT ), value 0
(EV_SYN), code 0( 0 -> 0, 0 == SYN_REPORT ), value 0
```

Comment: can you paste your event logs showing the btn_touch events together with other events around it?

Comment: I've added logs, thanks.

Comment: I see your device does not log the BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP but you can see BTN_TOUCH and BTN_TOOL_FINGER because it seems that your device thinks that the first TOUCH is not a finger, did you try touching with three fingers and checking the log?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BTN_TOOL_<DEVICE>` event tools. For your case it would be `BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP`. You can view more information about those here  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt

Comment: I don't get any `BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP` event codes at all in my input.  That's that mean there is something wrong with my driver?